# Display hyperlinks in jsPlumb nodes?

Tags: jsplumb

How do i display hyperlink in `jsplumb` nodes. I want users to to create task flow chart with links in nodes. I want to create a flowchart editor for my website users. I am able to create the nodes but i cant set a title or hyperlink in the node

Answer (score 1):

Any DOM element can behave as a `jsPlumb` node.

```
<div id="#myLinkDiv">
Start <br>
<a href="http://example.com">Link</a>
</div>

<div id='second'>
Second
</div>

jsPlumb.makeSource('myLinkDiv');
jsPlumb.makeTarget('second');
```

If you're worried about element drag interferring with anchor click, then you can use the filter parameter - http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/doc/connections.html#sourcefilter

```
jsPlumb.makeSource("foo", {
  filter:":not(a)"
});
```

Above means, don't interfere with operations related to `a (anchor tag)`.