# jsPlumb: Can't click() on a div inside a div that acts as a jsPlumb source/target

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsplumb

I'm using [jsPlumb](http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/demo/home/dom.html). 
My current functionality lets me create a `.project` div that can then have `.task` divs inside it. The `.project` div has 3 clickable buttons which all work using jQuery and the `.task`s inside the `.project` have a single close button which also works.

As can we seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/9yej6/3/
*(click the add project button then click on the green project and try to click on the X near some task - an alert should pop up)*

However, whenever I try to make the `.task`s a `makeTarget`/`makeSource` using jsPlumb it surpasses (probably not the best word) any other event done by jQuery. That is when I click on the X icon of the `.task` it instead acts as if I click on the `.task` itself and tries to create jsPlumb's bond.

As can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/9yej6/4/

So the following line no longer works (note I'm using the `on()` function since the `.project`/`.task` divs are dynamically created):

> ```
> $("#container").on('click','.task .close',function(e) {
>   alert('a task`s add was clicked');
> });
> ```

Initially the `addTask()` function was (which worked, but you can't add jsPlumb bonds):

> ```
> function addTask(parentId, index) {
>   var newState = $('<div>').attr('id', 'state' + index).addClass('task');
>
>   var close = $('<div>').addClass('close');
>   newState.append(close);
>
>   var title = $('<div>').addClass('title').text('task ' + index);;
>   newState.append(title);
>
>   $(parentId).append(newState);
> }
> ```

But when I add the `makeTarget()`/`makeSource()` calls to it, it seems to surpass any other jQuery event handling. Where my new `addTask()` function becomes:

> ```
> function addTask(parentId, index) {
>   var newState = $('<div>').attr('id', 'state' + index).addClass('task');
>
>   var close = $('<div>').addClass('close');
>   newState.append(close);
>
>   var title = $('<div>').addClass('title').text('task ' + index);;
>   newState.append(title);
>
>   $(parentId).append(newState);
>
>   jsPlumb.makeTarget(newState, {
>     anchor: 'Continuous'
>   });
>
>   jsPlumb.makeSource(newState, {
>     anchor: 'Continuous'
>   });
> }
> ```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the `filter` parameter to specify what element to be included for the object drag.

See my complete answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23903998/display-hyperlinks-in-jsplumb-nodes/23923668#23923668).

http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/doc/connections.html#sourcefilter

```
jsPlumb.makeSource("foo", {
  filter:":not(a)"
});
```

Above means, don't interfere with operations related to `a (anchor tag)`.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned,

```
$("#container").on('click','.task .close',function(e) {
    alert('a task`s add was clicked');
});
```

This code doesn't work becasue you have made the **'.task'** element as either **target** or **source** part of jsPlumb hence the mouse events will be handled by jsPlumb which prevents the default event handling(jQuery or pure JS) of those elements.

In such case you need to create a small rectangle DIV(refer image) from where the user can drag the connection instead of an entire DIV.

[image: Small rectangle DIV for connections]